# Nested 'if else' functions

Tags: python

Let's say we have to download a file, check if a value is True and if so, we need to alert the admin by email.

I would like to split up all the different things to do in easy to manage steps (functions). And then call each function one by one.

This create the following function:

```
def alert_admin():
    if download_file() == True: # File is downloaded, check if file is present
        if extract_file() == True: # Zip file contains the correct file
            if read_file() == True: # Read the file and the value is there
                if value_in_file() == True:
                    # send the admin an email
                    pass
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

This just doesn't feel right, is there a better way (a more pythonic) to check the outcome of certain functions and proceed to the next?

Comment: What should happen if any of the steps fail?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-EAFP. Rewrite the functions you're wrapping to have useful return values (e.g. the path of the downloaded file, that you can pass for extraction - only one should return a boolean by the looks of it) and error if they can't return them. Also note where you have **working code** that you think could be improved, [codereview.se] may be a better fit (but do check their requirements in the help center first).

Comment: Usually the best way is to inverse the logic so you may make flat structure;  First, check `if not download_file(): return`, then `if not extract_file(): return`, .. etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a couple of options for avoiding deeply nested control flows. A popular approach is the "return early pattern" - simply test whether the next step *fails*, then return immediately if it does:

```
def alert_admin():
    if not download_file():
        return
    if not extract_file():
        return
    if not read_file():
        return
    if not value_in_file():
        return

    # send email here
```

---

Another option is [*short-circuiting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). You chain the function calls with the `and` boolean operator - if the left-hand operand returns false the operator will skip evaluating the right-hand operand, thus ensuring "early return" as well:

```
def alert_admin():
    if download_file() and extract_file() and read_file() and value_in_file():
        # send email here
```

---

Finally, since the function calls all have the same signature, you can also store the "steps" in a list and iterate over that - this might make maintenance easier as you can simply add or remove function names to/from the list to update the behavior:

```
def alert_admin():
    required_steps = [
        download_file
        extract_file
        read_file
        value_in_file
    ]

    for step in required_steps:
        if not step():
            return

    # send email here
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I love the more readable option of the "return early pattern."